# How to register tagPrefix in app.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, app-config

in my ASP.net project's web.config I register the tagprefix cr as follows:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="cr" namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web,Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

I would like to start using configuration specific app.configs, but if I include the same setting in the app.config I get an error at compile time saying that the tagprefix is unrecognized

How can I force recognition of the tagprefix when it is in app.config instead of web.config

Comment: why are you doing this in an app config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.config` is not used in a web project; anything you put in that file might as well not exist; ASP.NET and IIS completely ignore that file.

Comment: yeah, I misunderstood the implementation of config file in asp.net.

Comment: Sad that there's no easy way to do file-based system-dependant configuration management

Comment: You can define separate files for most of the config sections. When I need machine-specific config, that's usually what I use.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, it just seems like a waste to reproduce the entire config file to allow for specific changes